# how can convert following snippet into JSP

Tags: java, jsp, logout

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
                                                   ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null ||
            session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") == null) {
            response.sendRedirect("Loginpage.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                               "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            response.setHeader("Pragma",
                               "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.                 response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req,
                           res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use above code in jsp to force user to redirect login page after logout
How can we convert it to jsp so that I can include it in my jsp pages.
I wriiten it like below and by doing this can we able to call that `chain.filter()` method

```
<%@ page import=" java.io.IOException"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.Filter"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.FilterChain"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.FilterConfig"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.ServletException"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.ServletRequest"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.ServletResponse"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse"%>
<%@ page import=" javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter"%>
<%
    //@Override         
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("userHash") == null)
        {  
        res.sendRedirect("/timescape/applicationservices/fileshare/vm/login/login.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1. 
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        } 
        else
          {
          chain.doFilter(request, response); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request. 
          }

    %>
```

Comment: Why? You can run that filter before all your JSP. That's exactly what Filters are for.

Comment: You don't need to call `chain.doFilter` from your JSP, because the JSP is already the last link of the processing chain. Just do what your JSP does here (and don't do it if you want to redirect instead). But seriously, just use the Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need the redirection in your JSP, you can easily do this:

```
<%
if (session == null || session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("Loginpage.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.                  
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.                 
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    return;
}
%>
```

This works since in a JSP, there's always an implicit variable called `response` that contains the [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) object, **and** there's always an implicit variable called `session` that contains the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) object.

Comment: You may want an `else` or a `return` of some sort otherwise the rest of the JSP will still be executed.

Comment: @mthmulders: I did as you said but after logout i am not able to get result as you said. But when I press refresh I redirect to login page. but I am looking for something different If I log out then Iam redirecting to login page but when I press back button it show me previous cached page.how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure either `session == null` or `session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") == null`? I checked the solution with a different condition inside the `if` and it performed the redirect the first time.

Comment: @ mthmulders: yes I am printing session variable using out.println. I am getting it as null but after logout when I press browser back button it shows me cached page with session variable value which we don't want.when I pressed refresh button it return me session variable as null and redirected me to login page.

Comment: please any help...I tried by setting http_equiv in HTML META tag to no-cache but that also not working.And if we use response.setHeader() then where to use it.I put in one jsp file and included that file in my main jsp.

Comment: The best way to go is using a Filter, as @Thilo suggested. My answer is here to show you how you can do it in a JSP, as that's what you asked. But if you want a good solution, the Filter would be much better, IMHO.

Comment: @Thilo/mthmulders : I don't know how to use filter can you give me an example using filter to accomplish my stucked task.